# Why is my image in the rich embed not loading

Tags: discord.js

My code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "birb")) {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(0x9370db)
    .setAuthor("ModularBot: Birb", "https://i.imgur.com/Y9HlaCp.png")
    .setImage("https://random.birb.pw/tweet/random")
    .setFooter("Powered by random.birb.pw")
    .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send({embed})
  }
});
```

Whenever I do that the image just appears blank with nothing in it

Comment: I think Discord just isn't detecting that this is actually an image. It's quirky like that, and not the first time I've seen it not work when similar services work fine. I can't test it, but you might try getting a random image url from `https://random.birb.pw/tweet/` and embedding the image from `https://random.birb.pw/img/<filename from previous step>`.

Comment: Discord doesn't necessarily embed all image links, and I tried posting the link itself on my private server, and it failed to embed.

Comment: I realize it's an old post, but there's not really any need to use `{embed}` in `message.channel.send`. You can simply just do `message.channel.send(embed)` which will also work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Discord requires you to send the actual file, not just a URL from the file. So, in your setImage line, you need to be sending the direct link for the file, such as https://random.birb.pw/tweet/random/1.png , or whatever the file name is called.

Answer (score 0):

Discord seems to require image links to be suffixed by an image file extension. I've only tested `.png` myself, but if there is no file extension, Discord assumes that the url is incorrect and ignores it to save computing time and space, as their servers keep a local copy of each image sent.

Comment: I have an extension at the end of the file, I checked full URL. Still not working for both jpg and webp

Answer (score 0):

Like previous replies said, Discord needs an image file. You can use snekfetch or superagent to fetch the image from the API and then send the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a thing. Even if you succeed in creating a REST API that can output a file when anybody ping the API, wich is what I did, **Discord won't accept any image that is not from a DNS server**. So you can put images from a website with a DNS name, like https://api.twitter.com/ , but not from any IP, not yours nor anyone's.

Comment: I have DNS name, still not working. They are webp images, so I tried with jpg just in case, still not working.

Comment: They may also block files not from trusted source (discord, imgurt, tenor, giphy, etc), so your best chance is uploading the image on the fly or uploading it somewhere in the discord CND and then using the raw image link

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by adding www to all my image urls.

Maybe it was an issue with my server?
My app is React with next.js and I'm hosted at Vercel.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I already have 'www'